# htaccess for admin panel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

How can I add .htaccess? I have two files it is .htaccess and .htpasswd. But this files work only when they are in folder admin. How can I add it only for admin. `admin.php` is in main directory. I mean that admin.php is not in folder admin.

`.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "For admins only!"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.../.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

`.htpasswd`

```
admin:$apr1$vVd1NLts$q4Grxt/...
```

Comment: You should not post here real login data despite it is encrypted because someone could get it and try to hack your admin are because you are showing your url too.

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

##### How to protect one file with htaccess and htpasswd

To protect only 1 file, but not all the directory, you need to have two files:

Example file: `mysite.com/oneFile.php`

First this lines in you root `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
<FilesMatch "oneFile.php">
AuthName "Authorized Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/public_html/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Now the file `.htpasswd` in the same directory of the `.htaccess` and the same of the `oneFile.php`:

This is the example user and pass for `oneFile.php`:

```
admin:$apr1$1kBnr3C4$ndhru5WIWlJdSFIn9F.gI0
```

**Attention**: To create this password do you need some `htpasswd Generator`

I hope you find it useful.